# Synchronous Socket: ReceiveTimeout

Tags: c#, sockets, synchronous, ioexception

I have a socket thread that blocks on read. I set the receivetimeout on the socket to 30 seconds; if no byte is read, the read goes into IO exception(inner exception: error code: 10060). I end the process and close the streams and set the thread to null. For some reason, I can't seem to close the socket connection. I am not sure where the error is. Below is my code:

```
public class SampleClientSocket
{       
    private Socket cltSocket = null;        
    private volatile bool readyToRecv = false;        
    NetworkStream ns;
    BinaryReader br;
    BinaryWriter wr;
    private string _caller = "SampleSocketClient";
    Thread workerThread;
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BeginWork();            
    }
    
    
    public void BeginWork()
    {            
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            cltSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            cltSocket.Connect(ipe);

            cltSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 30000;
        
            cltSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);            
        
            workerThread = new Thread(doWork_01);
            workerThread.Start();                
            readyToRecv = true;
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this._caller + f.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    
    
    
    private void doWork_01()
    {
        try
        {
            this.ns = new NetworkStream(this.cltSocket);
            this.br = new BinaryReader(this.ns);
            this.wr = new BinaryWriter(this.ns);
            readyToRecv = true;
            this._lastSocketRead = toUnixTime(DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "ERROR OPENING STREAMS.");
            readyToRecv = false;
        }
        
        while (this.readyToRecv)
        {
            
            bool _etxEncountered = false;

            MemoryStream currentMessage = new MemoryStream();
            byte buf = (byte)0;

            while (!_etxEncountered)
            {
                try
                {
                    buf = this.br.ReadByte();
                }
                catch (EndOfStreamException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "ERROR: END OF STREAM");
                    readyToRecv = false;
                    _etxEncountered = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "ERROR: Stream is closed!");
                    readyToRecv = false;
                    _etxEncountered = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException i)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "ERRORSTACK: IOException!" + i.StackTrace);
                    
                    //if the ReeceiveTimeout is reached an IOException will be raised...
                    /// with an InnerException of type SocketException an ErrorCode 10060
                    var socketExpert = i.InnerException as SocketException;
                    if (socketExpert.ErrorCode != 10060)
                    {   
                        Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "ERROR: IOException!" + socketExpert.ErrorCode);
                        readyToRecv = false;
                        _etxEncountered = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "Read: IOException for timeout! NOT DISCONNECTING");
                        readyToRecv = false;
                        _etxEncountered = true;
                        break;                            
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception f)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "Unknown exception" + f.StackTrace);
                    var socketExpert = f.InnerException as SocketException;
                    Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "Error code number: " + socketExpert.ErrorCode);

                    readyToRecv = false;
                    _etxEncountered = true;
                }
                if (buf.Equals(0x03) == true)
                {
                    _etxEncountered = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (buf.Equals(0x02) == false)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        currentMessage.WriteByte(buf);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            try { Thread.Sleep(10); }
            catch { }
        } // end while 

        EndWork();
    }
    
    public void EndWork()
    {
        try
        {
            readyToRecv = false;
            
            //close streams  
            this.br.BaseStream.Flush();
            this.br.Close();
            this.br.Dispose();
           
            this.wr.Flush();
            this.wr.Close();
            this.wr.Dispose();

            this.ns.Flush();
            this.ns.Close();
            this.ns.Dispose();

            
            this.cltSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            //this.cltSocket.Disconnect(true);
            this.cltSocket.Close();
            this.cltSocket.Dispose();
            this.cltSocket = null;                

            Console.WriteLine(this._caller + "GOODBYE...");
            try
            {
                this.workerThread.Join(1000);
                if (this.workerThread.IsAlive)
                {
                    this.workerThread.Abort();
                }
            }
            catch { }
            this.workerThread = null;
        }
        catch
        {
            this.readyToRecv = false;
            this.workerThread = null;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I can't seem to close the socket connection." What does this mean? Do you get an exception? What's that exception? Do you get a compiler error? Please explain what *does* happen.

Comment: The socket connection is still open where the other end can send data and my thread still receives bytes even after 1st 30 seconds and going into IOException.

Comment: Is the socket not closing or the Backgroundworker not closing.  Try from cmd.exe >Netstat -a and check status of port number to check state of socket.

Comment: The socket is not closing. In netstat -ao, I still see the client being connected. THe connection is established on port 5000; but, in my logs, the thread is being disposed of.

Comment: @jdweng: you pointed me in the right direction. There was a thread that wasn't disposing off correctly. So, the code never hit the close. Thank you for pointing out the issue. I am not sure as to how to mark your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a thread that wasn't hitting the Socket.Shutdown and socket.close. Thank you jdweng for pointing this to me.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be numerous problems with this code.

I think the reason for the problems is that you are trying to join the worker thread on the worker thread. `doWork_01` is run on a worker thread, and therefore `EndWork` will also run on the worker thread. this would be equivalent to calling `Thread.CurrentThread.Join()`, and will just deadlock. This deadlock will probably keep your process alive and might cause issues like not releasing the socket.

I see little reason for trying to use multiple threads here. The original thread just starts the worker and does nothing else. I would recommend removing all threading and just use local variables for the socket, and use `using` to ensure it is disposed.

To properly exit the process, use `Environment.Exit(0);`, `Application.Exit` or just return from Main.